# Spinners Visible in Type=Number Input Field on Mobile

Tags: html, css, user-interface, user-controls

Is it possible to preserve the spinner +/- 1 arrows on the right side of a type="number" field in mobile browsers (especially on iPads)? Usually they're not visible, but I'd like it to operate the same on mobile as on desktop.

(I quite like the Kendo UI's NumericTextBox component, but I can't justify buying the whole library just for that, sadly.)

Comment: Hi, Can you post some codes of what you´ve done so that we can advise further?
Thanks

Comment: I'm using Rails, so: <%= form.number_field :list_price, step: :any, class: "form-control"  %>